# Problema con crystal report 8.5 y vb6

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

Al querer abrir el reporte desde el vb6, en la parte superior del reporte en donde debería aparecer el boton de la impresora, el avance de hoja y para aumentar el tamaño, me muestra todos signos de pregunta. Similar a esto:
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Dicho reporte, en modo de diseño lo puedo abrir sin problemas. Me sucede lo mismo sin usar una conexion a base de datos.
Tengo configurada una impresora y ademas, por las dudas, lo probe poniendo diferentes impresoras predeterminadas.
La verdad que ya no sé qué probar.

Comment: qué impresora es?

Comment: Estimado, lo resolvi. Estaba faltando unas dll! gracias por responder!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.